# Text Preprocessing Translation Error Python

Tags: python, string

I was trying to translate tweet text using a deep translator but I found some issues.
Before translating the texts, I did some text preprocessing such as cleaning, removing emoji, etc. This is the ddefined functions of pre-processing :

```
def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
        u"\u2640-\u2642" 
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats
        u"\u3030"
                      "]+", re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)
def cleaningText(text):
    text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', text) # remove mentions
    text = re.sub(r'#[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', text) # remove hashtag
    text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]', '', text) # remove RT
    text = re.sub(r"http\S+", '', text) # remove link
    text = re.sub(r"[!@#$]", '', text) # remove link
    text = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', text) # remove numbers

    text = text.replace('\n', ' ') # replace new line into space
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) # remove all punctuations
    text = text.strip(' ') # remove characters space from both left and right text
    return text

def casefoldingText(text): # Converting all the characters in a text into lower case
    text = text.lower() 
    return text

def tokenizingText(text): # Tokenizing or splitting a string, text into a list of tokens
    text = word_tokenize(text) 
    return text

def filteringText(text): # Remove stopwors in a text
    listStopwords = set(stopwords.words('indonesian'))
    filtered = []
    for txt in text:
        if txt not in listStopwords:
            filtered.append(txt)
    text = filtered 
    return text
def stemmingText(text): # Reducing a word to its word stem that affixes to suffixes and prefixes or to the roots of words
    factory = StemmerFactory()
    stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text]
    return text
def convert_eng(text):
    text = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate_batch(text)
    return text
```

And here's the translate function :

```
def convert_eng(text):
    text = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(text)
    return text
```

this is an example of the expected result ( text in Indonesian)

```
text = '@jshuahaee Ketemu agnes mo lagii'
clean = cleaningText(text)
print('After cleaning ==> ', clean)
emoji = deEmojify(clean)
print('After emoji ==> ', emoji)
cf = casefoldingText(emoji)
print('After case folding ==> ', cf)
token = tokenizingText(cf)
print('After token ==> ', token)
filter= filteringText(token)
print('After filter ==> ', filter)

stem = stemmingText(filter)
print('After Stem ==> ', stem)

en = convert_eng(stem)
print('After translate ==> ', en)
```

Result :

```
After cleaning ==>  Ketemu agnes mo lagii
After emoji ==>  Ketemu agnes mo lagii
After case folding ==>  ketemu agnes mo lagii
After token ==>  ['ketemu', 'agnes', 'mo', 'lagii']
After filter ==>  ['ketemu', 'agnes', 'mo', 'lagii']
After Stem ==>  ['ketemu', 'agnes', 'mo', 'lagi']
After translate ==>  ['meet', 'agnes', 'mo', 'again']
```

But, I found issues when the sentences contain some dots, the error happened when after the stem process the text contain of [''] ( I don't know how to call this)

```
text = 'News update Meski kurang diaspirasi Shoppee yg korea minded  dalam waktu indonesa belaja di bulan November Lazada 1… '
clean = cleaningText(text)
print('After cleaning ==> ', clean)
emoji = deEmojify(clean)
print('After emoji ==> ', emoji)
cf = casefoldingText(emoji)
print('After case folding ==> ', cf)
token = tokenizingText(cf)
print('After token ==> ', token)
filter= filteringText(token)
print('After filter ==> ', filter)

stem = stemmingText(filter)
print('After Stem ==> ', stem)

en = convert_eng(stem)
print('After translate ==> ', en)
```

Result

```
After cleaning ==>  News update Meski kurang diaspirasi Shoppee yg korea minded  dalam waktu indonesa belaja di bulan November Lazada …
After emoji ==>  News update Meski kurang diaspirasi Shoppee yg korea minded  dalam waktu indonesa belaja di bulan November Lazada …
After case folding ==>  news update meski kurang diaspirasi shoppee yg korea minded  dalam waktu indonesa belaja di bulan november lazada …
After token ==>  ['news', 'update', 'meski', 'kurang', 'diaspirasi', 'shoppee', 'yg', 'korea', 'minded', 'dalam', 'waktu', 'indonesa', 'belaja', 'di', 'bulan', 'november', 'lazada', '…']
After filter ==>  ['news', 'update', 'diaspirasi', 'shoppee', 'yg', 'korea', 'minded', 'indonesa', 'belaja', 'november', 'lazada', '…']
After Stem ==>  ['news', 'update', 'aspirasi', 'shoppee', 'yg', 'korea', 'minded', 'indonesa', 'baja', 'november', 'lazada', '']
```

This is the error message

```
NotValidPayload                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-cb9390422d3c> in <module>
     14 print('After Stem ==> ', stem)
     15 
---> 16 en = convert_eng(stem)
     17 print('After translate ==> ', en)

<ipython-input-28-28bc36c96914> in convert_eng(text)
      8     return text
      9 def convert_eng(text):
---> 10     text = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate_batch(text)
     11     return text

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\google_trans.py in translate_batch(self, batch, **kwargs)
    195         for i, text in enumerate(batch):
    196 
--> 197             translated = self.translate(text, **kwargs)
    198             arr.append(translated)
    199         return arr

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\google_trans.py in translate(self, text, **kwargs)
    108         """
    109 
--> 110         if self._validate_payload(text):
    111             text = text.strip()
    112 

C:\Python\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\parent.py in _validate_payload(payload, min_chars, max_chars)
     44 
     45         if not payload or not isinstance(payload, str) or not payload.strip() or payload.isdigit():
---> 46             raise NotValidPayload(payload)
     47 
     48         # check if payload contains only symbols

NotValidPayload:  --> text must be a valid text with maximum 5000 character, otherwise it cannot be translated
```

My idea is to remove the **''**, i think that was the problem, but I have no idea how to do that.
Anyone, please kindly help me

Comment: Does your `stem` contain more than 5000 characters?

Comment: No it doesn't . Here is one example After Stem ==>  ['news', 'update', 'aspirasi', 'shoppee', 'yg', 'korea', 'minded', 'indonesa', 'baja', 'november', 'lazada', '']
I think it because the empty '' ( I don't know what to call this one)

Comment: You can try filtering it using list comprehension: `stem_clean = [s for s in stem if len(s.strip()) != 0]`

Comment: I tried , but the result is `After Stem_clean ==>  ['']`

Comment: Please try the updated one, mistakenly typed `==` instead `!=`

Comment: Is it possible that `filteringText(text)` can return `[]` because all words are stopwords? Add `if filter:` before getting list of stems. Also, do not use `filter` as a name of a variable, it is a built-in.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, I also experienced that and didn't have a solution for that, thanks a lot! Also, thank you for reminding me about the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce a bit of error checking into your code, and only process an expected data type. Your `convert_eng` function (that uses [`GoogleTranslator#translate_batch`](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator)) requires a list of non-blank strings as an argument (see `if not payload or not isinstance(payload, str) or not payload.strip() or payload.isdigit():` part), and your `stem` contains an empty string as the last item in the list.

Besides, it is possible that `filteringText(text)` can return `[]` because all words can turn out to be stopwords. Also, do not use `filter` as a name of a variable, it is a built-in.

So, change

```
filter= filteringText(token)
print('After filter ==> ', filter)

stem = stemmingText(filter)
print('After Stem ==> ', stem)
```

to

```
filter1 = filteringText(token)
print('After filter ==> ', filter1)

if filter1:
    stem = stemmingText(filter1)
    print('After Stem ==> ', stem)
    en = convert_eng([x for x in stem if x.strip() and not x.isdigit()])
    print('After translate ==> ', en)
```

I left out the `isinstance(x, str)` check because I assume you already know your list only contains strings.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution, but why did I get this kind of result? the word split into letters

`After translate ==>  [['n', 'e', 'w', 's'], ['u', 'p', 'd', 'a', 't', 'e'], ['a', 's', 'p', 'i', 'r', 'a', 's', 'i'], ['s', 'h', 'O', 'p', 'p', 'e', 'e'], ['and', 'g'], ['k', 'O', 'r', 'e', 'a'], ['m', 'i', 'n', 'd', 'e', 'd'], ['i', 'n', 'd', 'O', 'n', 'e', 's', 'a'], ['b', 'a', 'j', 'a'], ['n', 'O', 'v', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r'], ['l', 'a', 'With', 'a', 'd', 'a']]`

Comment: @AyuKrisnasari I found [the docs](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator), so you need to pass a list of non-blank strings there.

Comment: Hi, I put this code `[x for x in stem if x.strip() and not x.isdigit()` inside my stemming function and it working well . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AyuKrisnasari You are welcome. The error message was helpful to implement that right check and cleanup. Note you might need to add more logic to keep the same amount of strings returned from translations. Maybe think of using some kind of DO-NOT-TRANSLATE string token, like ##DNT## and you will know the returned target is to be discarded.